# How to understand when FileReader is done JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been reading this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/load_event) in order to find out when exactly the reader has finished reading the file and the text content of the file cant be obtained from the `reader.result`

Here is the function that is supposed to convert a `File` to a text/string and callback with the result:

```
function fileToStr(file: File, onDone: (text: string) => void) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        console.log(` e = `, e);
        if (e.loaded === e.total) {
            console.log(` File text = `, reader.result);
            onDone(reader.result as string);
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is that I think I don't understand what the documentation is saying i.e.

> ProgressEvent.loaded Read only A 64-bit unsigned integer value
> indicating the amount of work already performed by the underlying
> process. The ratio of work done can be calculated by dividing total by
> the value of this property. When downloading a resource using HTTP,
> this only counts the body of the HTTP message, and doesn't include
> headers and other overhead.

If I understand correctly this ratio `e.total / e.loaded` will always be greater than 1 because `e.total >= e.loaded`. Meaning this ratio could be between 1 and infinity.
Am I correct to assume that the only way to figure out when the file reading has finished is to check `e.loaded === e.total` or `e.total / e.loaded === 1`?

Comment: there is a `loadend` and `progress` event too you can use them instead. The `loadend` is emitted when the reader is done reading the file (with a success or failure) but the read has ended.

Comment: I don't think that you need to check for the total. Mozilla documentation states that "load" is fired when is loaded succesfully: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/load_event. You can check on the left for the other events, like loadend, loadstart or progress.

Comment: _"The ratio of work done can be calculated by dividing total by the value of this property."_ - sometimes the MDN gets the phrasing wrong, it happens. When you actually check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent/loaded, there it says, _"The ratio of work done can be calculated with the property and ProgressEvent.total"_ Dividing `loaded` by `total` really is the only thing that actually makes sense. Then you get a progess on a scale between 0 and 1 (which then also easily translates into a percentage value, if multiplied by 100.)

Comment: @CBroe
That is my understanding as well. I wanted to check with someone native English speaker. Instead of doubting MDN words, I prefer to doubt my understanding of English, because I am not a native speaker.
Anyhow your comment basically answered my question.